# Scala, Spark, extracting parts of strings

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to extract parts of a string that match a regex.
My string looks like:
10001_20180101_UPD_FILE1

it can look also like:

10043_20180102_DEL_FILE2

So I try to extract parts of it with this code:

```
val pattern = "([0-9]+)_(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})_(UPD|DEL)_*".r
        val patern = splittet.map {
          case pattern(id, timestamp, typee, name) => "yes"
        }
        println(patern)
      }
```

or with this code:

```
val pattern = "([0-9]+)_([yyyy][mm][dd])_(UPD|DEL)_(FILE1)".r
 val pattern(id, timestamp, typee, name) = "10001 20180101 UPD FILE1"
```

but I have an issue:

```
18/07/17 14:34:17 WARN SparkContext: Using an existing SparkContext; some configuration may not take effect.
Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: 1 (of class java.lang.Character)
```

Does anyone know what do I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code. The following is working fine:

```
val pattern = raw"([0-9]+)_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_(UPD|DEL)_(.*)".r

"10043_20180102_DEL_FILE2" match {
  case pattern(id, year, month, day, typee, name) => s"$id $year $month $day $typee $name "
  case _ => "No match"
}
```

You should always specify a default case (`case _ => "No match"`) to avoid errors.

Your regex also had some problems. If you want to match the name, you should add the group `(.*)` at the end. Also, use raw string to write clearer regex.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
It prints me "No match" ..
Do you think you know why?

Comment: You are probably giving it a string that does not match. The match will work only for string in the format you defined.  
Have a look here: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/GL6sYCT0QEiTqnGU7d7G6Q
to try it.

Comment: Thanks, I found my mistake!